# Using Excel in Visual Basic

Tags: excel, vb.net, winforms, excel-interop

I am currently using Excel 2013 and Visual Studio 2017. I have added the Microsoft Excel 15.0 Object Library reference.

Following this tutorial:

http://www.visual-basic-tutorials.com/WriteToExcel2007.php

I encounter an error that does not allow me to read/write to/from Excel, and I am not sure what causes this.

My Code:

```
Imports Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel

Public Class Form1

    Dim APP As New Excel.Application
    Dim worksheet As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim workbook As Excel.Workbook

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        workbook = APP.Workbooks.Open("Path\Try1.xlsx")
        worksheet = workbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnGo_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnGo.Click
        TextBox1.Text = worksheet.Cells(1, 1).Value <------- ERROR LINE

        TextBox2.Text = worksheet.Cells(1, 2).Value
    End Sub
End Class
```

The Error when pressing the button:

```
System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'
```

What could cause this? Are there any better ways of reading/writing from Excel using Visual Basic?

Comment: in which line are you getting that error?

Comment: I specified it in the code snippet, though it is at this line: TextBox1.Text = worksheet.Cells(1, 1).Value

Comment: This error means you're trying to use an object for calling a method or getting value of a property but the object is null. For example TextBox1 is null and can't get `.Text` or worksheet.Cells(1, 1) is getting null and can't get `.Value`. Have you added these Text boxes to your winform?

Comment: I have added the textboxes, so I guess its the latter...

Comment: I found the problem, I literally used "Path\Try1.xlsx" as a way to find the path of the spreadsheet, but now I included the full path directly leading to the spreadsheet and it worked. I guess Path doesn't do anything(I'm new :( )

Comment: There is a better way.. use [EPPlus](https://github.com/JanKallman/EPPlus) or Closed Xml. Not interop (unless you really need to)!